# C++ classes - the most frequent object in an array

Tags: c++, class, object

I have implemented 3 classes: Location, Address, Route. The Address class contains a Location object, and the Route class contains an array of Address objects. In the main function I've created an array of Route objects. What I want to do is to find the most frequent 5 addresses appearing in the Route array. I think I should  use a frequency vector, but I'm not sure how implementation should be done. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a solution Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Location
{
    double lat, lon;

    char *emi;
public:
    Location(double = 0, double = 0, char* = NULL);
    virtual ~Location();
    Location& operator= (const Location &);
    Location(const Location&);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Location &);
    void operator! ();
    void print1() const;
    char* getem()
    {
        return emi;
    }
protected:
private:
};
Location::Location(double lat, double lon, char *emi)
{
    this->lat = lat;
    this->lon = lon;
    if (emi != NULL)
    {
        this->emi = new char[strlen(emi) + 1];
        strcpy(this->emi, emi);
    }

}
Location&Location::operator= (const Location &l)
{
    if (this != &l)
    {
        this->lon = l.lon;
        this->lat = l.lat;
        if (l.emi != NULL)
        {
            this->emi = new char[strlen(l.emi) + 1];
            strcpy(this->emi, l.emi);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
Location::Location(const Location &la)
{
    lat = la.lat;
    lon = la.lon;
    if (la.emi != NULL)
    {
        emi = new char[strlen(la.emi) + 1];
        strcpy(emi, la.emi);
    }
}
Location::~Location()
{
    if (emi != NULL)
        delete[]emi;
}
void Location::operator! ()
{
    if (!(strcmp(this->emi, "north")))
    {
        delete[]this->emi;
        this->emi = new char[strlen("south") + 1];
        strcpy(this->emi, "south");
    }
    else
    {
        delete[]this->emi;
        this->emi = new char[strlen("north") + 1];
        strcpy(this->emi, "north");
    }
}
void Location::print1() const
{
    cout << "lon: " << this->lon << endl;
    cout << "lat: " << this->lat << endl;
    cout << "emi: " << this->emi << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const Location &l)
{
    os << "lon: " << l.lon << endl;
    os << "lat: " << l.lat << endl;
    os << "emi: " << l.emi << endl;
    os << endl;
    return os;
}
class Address
{

    char *desc;
    Location l;
    char *country;
    public`:
        Address(char *, const Location &, char *);
    virtual ~Address();
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Address &);
    void print();
    bool em();
    char *getDesc()
    {
        return desc;
    };

protected:
private:
};
Address::Address(char *desc, const Location &loc1, char *country)
{
    if (desc != NULL)
    {
        this->desc = new char[strlen(desc) + 1];
        strcpy(this->desc, desc);
    }
    if (country != NULL)
    {
        this->country = new char[strlen(country) + 1];
        strcpy(this->country, country);
    }
    this->l = loc1;
}
Address::~Address()
{
    if (country != NULL)
        delete[]country;
    if (desc != NULL)
        delete[]desc;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const Address&a)
{
    os << "desc: " << a.desc << endl;
    os << "country: " << a.country << endl;
    a.l.print1();
    return os;
}
void Address::print()
{
    cout << "desc: " << desc << endl;
    cout << "country: " << country << endl;
    this->l.print1();
}
bool Address::em()
{
    return (!(strcmp(l.getem(), "south")));
}

class Route
{
    Address **r;
    int dim_max;
    int dim_curr;
public:
    Route(int = 9);
    void print2();
    void add(char *, double, double, char *, char*);
    virtual ~Route();
    int lRoute();

protected:
private:
};
Route::Route(int d)
{
    this->dim_max = d;
    dim_curr = 0;
    r = new Address *[dim_max];
}
void Route::add(char *d, double l, double l2, char *em, char *t)
{
    r[dim_curr] = new Address(d, Location(l, l2, em), t);
    dim_curr++;
}
Route::~Route()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim_curr; i++)
        delete r[i];
    delete[]r;
}
void Route::print2()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dim_curr; i++)
        r[i]->print();
}
int Route::lRoute()
{
    return dim_curr;
}

int main()
{

    Route **sirR;
    sirR = new Route *[5];
    sirR[0] = new Route(3);
    sirR[1] = new Route(3);
    sirR[2] = new Route(2);
    sirR[3] = new Route(4);
    sirR[4] = new Route(2);
    sirR[0]->add(" Address 1", 23.43, 21.43, "south", "country1");
    sirR[0]->add("Address 2", 23.431, 21.443, "south", "country2");
    sirR[0]->add("Address 3", 43.23, 13.42, "north", "country3");
    sirR[1]->add("Address 4", 13.431, 123.432, "south", "country4");
    sirR[1]->add("Address 5", 324.123, 43.13, "north", "country5");
    sirR[1]->add("Address 6", 43.123, 43.12, "south", "country 6");
    sirR[2]->add("Address 7", 23.31, 321.32, "north", "country 7");
    sirR[2]->add("Address 8", 43.12, 43.12, "south", "country 8");
    sirR[3]->add("Address 9", 23.42, 64.21, "north", "country 9");
    sirR[3]->add("Address 10", 64.23, 75.21, "south", "country 10");
    sirR[3]->add("Address 11", 75.13, 75.124, "north", "country 11");
    sirR[3]->add("Address 12", 75.12, 54.342, "south", "country 12");
    sirR[4]->add("Address 13", 543.245, 34.24, "north", "country 13");
    sirR[4]->add("Address 14", 54.123, 84.12, "south", "country 14");
    sirR[4]->print2();
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: I don't use strings because the teacher told me to use char.

Comment: *"I don't use strings because the teacher told me to use char"* - Is the lack of indentation your way of getting back at your teacher?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?  The code is hard to read.  I also doubt it's actually a minimal example.

Comment: Do you know about std::map or std::unordered_map or are you expected to write your own "frequency vector"?

Comment: @doctorlove I don't know about std::map or std::unordered_map

Comment: They are exactly right for looking up stuff e.g. mapping an address to a count. Ah well.

Comment: _"I don't use strings because the teacher told me to use char."_ Yet another teacher who is definitely focussing on the things that really matter at this stage in the learning...

Comment: `std::string` is just many chars, so you wouldnt even go against your teachers requirement if you used string

Comment: What makes two addresses equal? What happens if each is unique - should you return them all?

Comment: @doctorlove It's not specified, I think two addresses are equal if all their attributes are equal. It's not specified what to do if each is unique either, I think I should return them all as you said.

Comment: *" I don't use strings because the teacher told me to use char"*. So write your own my_string.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how to use a standard map to get the address counts.
You could then find the top five of these.
It will pull out some propblems with the design and ways to strip back the code.

Consider using `const char *` in the constructors of your objects, rather than just `char *`.  In fact, consider asking why you were told to use `char *` rather than `const char *` - make sure you know the difference first though.

Also,

```
Route **sirR;
sirR = new Route *[5];
sirR = new Route *[5];
sirR[0] = new Route(3);
sirR[1] = new Route(3);
sirR[2] = new Route(2);
sirR[3] = new Route(4);
sirR[4] = new Route(2);
```

could just be

```
Route sirR[5];
```

end use

```
sirR[0].add(" Address 1", 23.43, 21.43, "south", "country1");
```

instead of

```
sirR[0]->add(" Address 1", 23.43, 21.43, "south", "country1");
```

and so on - as it stands you don't `delete` the array you `new`ed.

---

As it stands the only way to get information back out of your route array is by printing to standard out.

You need to give some thought to what makes addresses equal.
The class needs an equals operator, or other way to compare addresses.

In order to use `std::map` we need to define a less than operator.
This will get you started, if you add it inside `Address`:

```
bool operator < (const Address & lhs) const
{
    return strcmp(desc, lhs.desc) < 0;
}
```

It's not using all the fields - you can think how to extend it.

If we now include the map header

```
#include <map>
```

we can use a map.
This isn't the best or only way to do this, but it will show the problems we have trying to find the addresses out.

Your addresses get made in the routes, when you call `add`, so we can track them there if all the routes can see the same map.

```
class Route
{
    static std::map<Address, size_t> frequency; //<- keep track
    Address **r;
    int dim_max;
    int dim_curr;
public:
    Route(int = 9);
    void print2();
    void add(const char *, double, double, const char *, const char*);
    virtual ~Route();
    int lRoute();
    std::map<Address, size_t> frequencies() //<- so we can find use these in main
    {
        return frequency;
    }

protected:
private:
};
std::map<Address, size_t> Route::frequency;//<-- define the static data member
```

This is a hack to work round not being able to query the addresses after they go in a route.

Now, using this hack, the `add` function can populate the map:

```
void Route::add(const char *d, double l, double l2, const char *em, const char *t)
{
    r[dim_curr] = new Address(d, Location(l, l2, em), t);
    ++frequency[*r[dim_curr]]; //count addresses
    dim_curr++;
}
```

Whenever you make an address it gets counted now.

At the end of main, before you return 0, you can add code to see all the counts:

```
for(auto & items : sirR[0].frequencies())
{
    std::cout << items.first << ' ' << items.second << '\n';
}
```

For your data they are all unqiue.
For other data you could then count the top few.
I haven't explicitly done this for you.

As your code stands, you can't see the addresses in the routes.
You can only print them.
You need to change your code around to be able to access these.

If you are avoiding standard data structures and making your own as a learning exercise, you could have an array of names and a matching array of counts, and sweep through the names each time you add a new address and increment the matching count.